# Taylor expansion of $\left(\int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}a(t')dt'\right)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, taylor-expansion

$$\left(\int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}a(t')dt'\right), a(t) \text{ is scalar}$$

Is the taylor expansion of $\left(\int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}a(t')dt'\right)$ at $t$ =
$$\left(\int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}a(t')dt'\right) = a(t)\Delta t + \frac{1}{2}\frac{da}{dt}(t) \Delta t^2 + \frac{1}{3!}\frac{d^2a}{dt^2}(t) \Delta t^3 +  \frac{1}{4!}\frac{d^3a}{dt^3}(t) \Delta t^4 \cdots$$?

In big O notation: 
Is the taylor expansion of $\left(\int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}a(t')dt'\right)$ at $t$ =
$$\left(\int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}a(t')dt'\right) = a(t)\Delta t + O(\Delta t^2) + O(\Delta t^3) + O(\Delta t^4) \cdots$$  ?

Comment: I think your $1/n!$ are off by one on each term. At 0th order in $\Delta t$ you have a coefficient of 0, 1^{st} order is a(t), so on and so forth. What you have is the Taylor expansion of $a(t + \Delta t) \Delta t$ about $\Delta t = 0$

Comment: if $a$ is $C^{K}$  : $a(t+h) = \sum_{k =0}^K \frac{a^{(k)}(t)}{k!} h^k + o(h^{K})$. then let $f_t(h) = \int_t^{t+h} a(u) du$, $f_t(0) = 0$ and $f_t'(h) = a(t+h)$ so that $$f_t(h) =  \sum_{k =0}^{K+1} \frac{f_t^{(k)}(0)}{k!} h^{k} + o(h^{K+1}) = \sum_{k =0}^K \frac{a^{(k)}(t)}{(k+1)!} h^{k+1} + o(h^{K+1})$$

Comment: @user1952009  Thanks. but I need term by term order. So I think I have to use big 0 for each term instead of one small 0. Is my big O notation correct?

Comment: if $a$ is $C^{K+1}$, then the $o(h^K)$ term is $\frac{a^{(K+1)}(t)}{(K+1)!} h^{K+1} + o(h^{K+1}) = \mathcal{O}(h^{K+1})$

Comment: You should be good now.

Comment: @Kitter Catter i have corrected

Comment: @user1952009 does the use of big O and small o need $h$ smaller than 1?

Comment: here it is $o$ and $\mathcal{O}$ as $h \to 0$ (you have to read it : as $h \to 0$, $a(t+h)$ is a polynomial in $h$ of degree $K$ plus an error term much smaller than $h^K$)

Comment: @user1952009 Is $\left(\int_{t}^{t+\Delta t}a(t')dt'\right) = a(t)\Delta t + O(\Delta t^2) + O(\Delta t^3) + O(\Delta t^4) \cdots$ correct? Can I say $\frac{1}{4!}\frac{d^3a}{dt^3}(t) \Delta t^4 = O(\Delta t^4)$?

Comment: so you don't understand the big O and little o notation ? nothing complicated https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation but you need to specify you are comparing asymptotically as $h \to 0$ (in my notation that is better)

Comment: @user1952009 Big O notation does say that: $\frac{1}{4!}\frac{d^3a}{dt^3}(t) \Delta t^4 = O(\Delta t)^4)$ for $\Delta t > 1$, but I am not sure if it holds for $(\Delta t) < 1$?

Comment: when $h \to 0$,  $h^4$ is much smaller than $h$. When $h \to + \infty$, it is the opposite. So $f(h) = o(g(h))$ as $h \to 0$ is completely different to $f(h) = o(g(h))$ as $h \to + \infty$

Comment: @user1952009 Yes in that case how can I amend $\frac{1}{4!}\frac{d^3a}{dt^3}(t) \Delta t^4 = O(\Delta t^4)$ in terms of big O or small o notation. $\frac{1}{4!}\frac{d^3a}{dt^3}(t) \Delta t^4$ is of order $\Delta t^4$ definitely no matter if $\Delta t < or > 1$. But $\Delta t < 1$ is my case and in big O notation $\Delta t$ seems to always increase.

Comment: read what I wrote, and the definition, and a course (and stop writing $\Delta t$ when I told you 50 times to write it $h$)

Comment: @user1952009  yes thanks I have now read it.

Comment: @user1952009 you mentioned that $o(h^K) = f(h^{K+1}) + o(h^{K+1}) = O(h^{K+1})$ as $h \rightarrow 0$. I wonder if I can say for just a single term $f(h^4)$: that $f(h^4) = o(h^3) = O(h^4)$ as $h \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: no, I wrote that if $a$ is $C^{K}$ then as $h \to 0$ : $a(t+h) = \sum_{k=0}^K \frac{a^{(k)}(t)}{k!} h^k + o(h^K)$ and if it is $C^{K+1}$ then $a(t+h) = \sum_{k=0}^{K+1} \frac{a^{(k)}(t)}{k!} h^k + o(h^{K+1})$ i.e. $a(t+h) - \sum_{k=0}^K \frac{a^{(k)}(t)}{k!} h^k = \frac{a^{(K+1)}(t)}{(K+1)!} h^{K+1} + o(h^{K+1}) = \mathcal{O}(h^{K+1})$

Comment: now what you ask means nothing, and it is obvious what you can write once you understood the definition of $o$ and $\mathcal{O}$, in particular it is obvious that $h^2 = o(h)$ and $h^2 = \mathcal{O}(h)$ when $h \to 0$